# find a process to terminate after a security event

Tags: c++, mfc

I run a process by `CreateProcess(...)`. I get and keep the `PROCESS_INFORMATION`.
In a normal situation, I'm waiting for the process to be finished by:

```
HANDLE hProcess = pWaitingThreadData->GetProcessHandle();
::WaitForSingleObject (hProcess, INFINITE);
```

I also have a security function, that got a message if a security event occurs.
In this security function, I want to terminate immediately the process I have ran before.

the security function can occur anytime (not just while the process is open) and it's a general function.
I call it with the MESSAGE_MAP by:
ON_REGISTERED_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_SECEVENT, OnThreadSecEvent).
So I can't pass a paremeter of the process to the security function.

The problem is, in the security function I don't have the `processID` or `threadID` of that process.

How can I find and terminate that process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to send the `processID` as part of the message to your security function.

Comment: But the security function can occur anytime and it's a general function. I call it with the MESSAGE_MAP by     ON_REGISTERED_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_SECEVENT, OnThreadSecEvent).